# Enzyme 3 get attributes of rendered DOM-node

Tags: javascript, reactjs, enzyme

I get this html from `myDomNode.html();`

```
<div aria-expanded="true"> {{someChildren}} </div>
```

In my test I want to check that `aria-expanded` is set to true.

With enzyme 2.x and react 15.x this was working: 
`expect(myDomNode.attr('aria-expanded')).toBeTruthy();` but after the update of react to 16.x and enzyme 3.x I get an error after the update that the value is undefined. I couldn't find any helpful hints in the documentation.

I'm getting the `myDomNode` like this:

```
const domNode = expanded => render(<Component expanded={expanded} />);
const myDomNode = domNode(true);
```

And render is imported from enzyme.
I'm using the `enzyme-adapter-react-16`

```
Enzyme.configure({adapter: new Adapter()});
```

Interesting is the fact that `myDomNode.is('div');` and `myDomNode.is('[aria-expanded="true"]')` is also false.

How do I repair the test after updating?

Just for reference, this is one of the failing tests: https://github.com/mstruebing/PackageFactory.Guevara/blob/updateReact/packages/react-ui-components/src/ToggablePanel/toggablePanel.spec.js#L130

Comment: How are you retrieving domNode? https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/guides/migration-from-2-to-3.md#with-mount-getnode-should-not-be-used-instance-does-what-it-used-to does this help you?

Comment: Currently I'm doing smth like this: `const domNode = expanded => render(<Component expanded={expanded} />);`

Comment: And render is imported from enzyme.

Comment: Have you installed an appropriate adapter? http://airbnb.io/enzyme/#upgrading-from-enzyme-2x-or-react--16

Comment: Yes I have. I'm using `enzyme-adapter-react-16`

Comment: You also initialized the adapter as stated in the docs? You must call const testDomNode = domNode(true); Only after doing this you can call testDomNode.is('div'). Are you doing this? We need more info

Comment: I'm doing: `Enzyme.configure({adapter: new Adapter()});`

Comment: And:     `const myDomNode = domNode(true);` -- that means some occurences of `domNode` has to be changed to `myDomNode` I will update the sample code

Comment: If you want to see the full code here is one of the failing ones: https://github.com/mstruebing/PackageFactory.Guevara/blob/updateReact/packages/react-ui-components/src/ToggablePanel/toggablePanel.spec.js#L130

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cloned your repo and executed the tests. I changed some functions and this is what I did:

```
const getHeaderDomNode = panelDomNode => panelDomNode['0'].children[0];

test('open ToggablePanel should render a <ToggablePanel.Header/> with an "aria-expanded" attribute of "true".', () => {
    const wrapper = fullyRenderToggablePanel(true);
    expect(getHeaderDomNode(wrapper).attribs['aria-expanded']).toBeTruthy();
});
```

An important thing is that when I saw the 'wrapper' variable with `console.log(wrapper)` I found this:

```
{
    '0':
        { 
            type: 'tag',
            name: 'section',
            namespace: 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml',
            attribs: { class: 'baseClassName isOpenClassName' },
            'x-attribsNamespace': { class: undefined },
            'x-attribsPrefix': { class: undefined },
            children: [ [Object], [Object] ],
            parent: null,
            prev: null,
            next: null,
            root:
            { 
                type: 'root',
                name: 'root',
                namespace: 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml',
                attribs: {},
                'x-attribsNamespace': {},
                'x-attribsPrefix': {},
                children: [Array],
                parent: null,
                prev: null,
                next: null 
            } 
        }, 
    options:
        { 
            withDomLvl1: true,
            normalizeWhitespace: false,
            xml: false,
            decodeEntities: true 
        },
    length: 1,
    _root: [Circular] 
}
```

So, It seems that if you want to access the children you have to do this:

```
wrapper['0'].children
```

And now the attributes are in an object with literal objects inside, so if you want to get an attribute (e.g.: 'arial-expanded') you must do this:

```
wrapper['0'].children[0]['arial-expanded']
```

Comment: Great, this helped me a lot and tests are now repaired :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also just search for the element using the attribute syntax and extract the text:

`expect(wrapper.find('[aria-expanded]').prop('aria-expanded')).toBeTruthy();`

http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/selector.html